Speaker repair to centres thereof
I have a couple of nice 12" speakers, nice, except their centres are imploded, probably by someone pushing them in.
Is there a way to restore them to their former glory, or, in fact, will it make no difference at all, whether the centres are 'dimpled' as in have been pushed in from their normal convex shape, or better left alone. They just don't look right.

I'm curious why the title is worded in a strange old-fashioned way, but not motivated enough to edit it to be something like "Repairing centres of speakers", or even better, "Speaker dustcap repair".

@ToddWilcox - 'cos I'm very much old school, but I believe it can still be understood! Maybe I should have started it with 'So-'

Obligatory xkcd: https://xkcd.com/771/

@IconDaemon - forsooth! Not sure whether you're being obliging or taking the rise. But, while language is changing - on a daily rate  sometimes - it doesn't have to mean that former words/phrases are totally redundant, surely?

Yea, verily, Thou art gruntled and full of mickle merriment, Tim. What once was superannuated will be renewed and refreshed.

@IconDaemon - more disgruntled at comments! My grunt has rarely been more dissed..!

I understand a fury in your words / But not the words.
— OTHELLO, ACT 4 SCENE 2, LINES 32-33; DESDEMONA TO OTHELLO
O, that my tongue were in the thunder's mouth! / Then with a passion would I shake the world
— KING JOHN, ACT 3 SCENE 4, LINES 39-40; CONSTANCE TO KING PHILIP

The common opinion is that a dented dust cap on a speaker does not appreciably affect the sound, even if it does technically make a small difference.  It is really a cosmetic issue.
This is especially true if your 12" speakers will be used in a hi-fi system, where the crossover will have them only producing low frequencies whose wavelengths are large compared to the surface details of the speaker.
The most common way to pop out a dented dust cap seems to be by puncturing it with a very fine needle and pushing it back out from the inside.  A small amount of adhesive on a toothpick could also work, provided you have some way to un-glue it without ripping the dome.  Suction can work as well- I've seen that recommended for dome tweeters- but I'd use my lungs and not a vacuum cleaner.

They're for electric guitar use, not hi-fi.

The thing is the dust cap should be airtight when you’re done with it, so if you poke a hole, you want to find some way to plug it afterwards. Also replacing a dust cap isn’t very hard as long as you can find a replacement one that is the exact same size.

@Tim Honestly for a guitar amp I wouldn’t even bother at all. The most I might do is use it as an excuse to try a different flavor of driver in the amp or cabinet.

As long as you stick to playing songs by The Ramones and The Stooges, you should be just fine.

@Sparquelito - I'm stuffed then. I only play music.
